# "special props warning" without referencing `ref` nor `key`

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am unable to reproduce it in plunker. In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zatziky/64scwws7/1/) I have the very same setup like I have in my project with these differences: `separate files` & `webpack` - yet it is working there...

In one file I have:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const Component = function (props) {
    return (
        <div>MyComponent has {props.value} bapples</div>
    )
};


Component.propTypes = {
    value: React.PropTypes.number
};

// export default A;

const HigherOrderComponent = function(props) {
    return (
        <Component {...props} />
    )
};

export default HigherOrderComponent;
```

Then when I try to connect to `redux-store` in another file

```
import HigherOrderComponent from './HigherOrderComponent';

export default ReactRedux.connect()(HigherOrderComponent);
```

I receive [special props warning](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/special-props.html):

> Element: `ref` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.
>
> Element: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.

But I am not using `ref` nor `key` at all... I've googled but I only hit irrelevant issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that I came up with (may need to be slightly modified for your context):

```
let props = Object.assign({},this.props)

delete props.key
delete props.ref

return <div> { React.cloneElement(props.children, props) } </div>
```

So in your `HigherOrderComponent` you would do this (untested):

```
const HigherOrderComponent = function(incomingProps) {
    let props = Object.assign({}, incomingProps)

    delete props.key
    delete props.ref

    return (
        <Component {...props} />
    )
};
```

Comment: funny solution, indeed. :-) The `props` doesn't have `key` neither `ref`.